# React/Redux: Can't pass State to components and wrappers are completely inactive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working in React with Redux and trying to pass my initial state to components using `mapStateToProps` through a wrapper, however nothing is making it through to the component to use as a `prop` The console logs of states in the components return `undefined` and there is no visible console log from the wrappers themselves.

I have placed the `store, reducer, action` and `initial state` in the main index.js file in order to see what is going on but I can't work out why nothing is passing through.

Here is a link to a sandbox containing the project:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-night-e535o

Comment: You should also check if you're using the correct "connected" components. In App.js, is the Start component imported correctedly?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PlayerList from "./PlayerList";
const mapStateToProps = ({ state }) => {
  console.log(state);
  console.log(1);

  return;

  state;
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PlayerList);
```

In this code the line, you are using destructuring assignment

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ state }) => {
```

({state}) is looking for an element state in the first param you should remove the {} (there is no element state in your redux state)

Also you do not return anything.

Your code should look like this :

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PlayerList from "./PlayerList";
const mapStateToProps = ( state) => {
  console.log(state);
  console.log(1);

  return state;
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PlayerList);
```

Comment: I changed it so it was no longer deconstructed, but still getting the error 
```TypeError: can't access property "map", players is undefined``` so state is being passed to Start now but not to the PlayerList.

Comment: Your import statement are wrong for exemple in Start.js you are importing 
`import PlayerList from "../PlayerList/PlayerList";`
but it should be 
`import PlayerList from "../PlayerList/index";`

Personnaly I do not use two separates file and put the content of your index.js in PlayerList.js